# java code: if statement not the expected output

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

The output should be the salary + rise 4% or 6%. This is my code:

```
int x = input.nextInt();    //x 1,2 or3//
System.out.println("enter the sallary:");
int y = input.nextInt();    // salary//
if (x == 1) {
    double z = 6/100*y + y;
    System.out.print("excellent ur sallary is :");
    System.out.print(z);
} else {
    double z = 4/100*y + y;
    System.out.print("good ur sallary is :");
    System.out.print(z);
 }
```

But the output is always only the value of y (the salary without the rising) !

Also how I can print that sentence and the variable z in the same line? Like this for example:

```
System.out.print("good ur sallary is :", z);
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Because `6/100` is `0` in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Declare y as a double, not an int.

Comment: Or just cast the 6 (e.g. `(double)6/100*y+y`)

Comment: BTW the downvotes are a bit brutal.  It's not an obvious error to someone that is relatively new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part: When you write `6/100*y`, it's equal to `(6/100)*y`. But the expression `6/100` is integer division, which is equal to 0. Thus `0*y` = 0. What you want to do is change `6/100` to `0.06`, and `4/100` to `0.04`.

Second part: The correct syntax is `System.out.println("YOUr salary is: " + z);`.

Comment: Without explaining why those changes should be made, this is a comment and not a (good) answer.